# How to execute and merge multiple functions result by using Lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash, material-ui, jss

Suppose that we have 2 different functions (or more) which accept an one argument from some executor and return the result object. Let me show in an example:

```
const style_1 = theme => ({
  header : {
      color : theme.primary
    }
})

const style_2 = theme => ({
  header : {
      backgroundColor : theme.secondary,
      color : "red"
    }
})
```

I want to execute them and merge the resulted object into an one! In case of objects it's a trivial task eg.

```
const style_1 = {
  header : {
      color : theme.primary
    }
}

const style_2 = {
  header : {
      backgroundColor : theme.secondary,
      color : "red"
    }
}

 const res = {...style_1, ...style_2}
```

expected result is

```
 { 
   header :
     { 
       backgroundColor : "black",
       color : "red"
      }
}
```

But in case of functions it's becomes a lil bit annoying.

So question is. Is it possible to implement what I want? (via Lodash or by using something else)

I've decided that I might create something like that

```
const style_1 = theme => ({
    header : {
        color : theme.secondary
        backgroundColor : "black"
    },
    footer : {
        color : "purple"
    }
})

const style_2 = (theme, extendStyles) => {
    const extendStyles = extendStyles(theme);

    return {
        header : {
            color : theme.primary,
            ...extendsStyles.header
        },
        ...extendStyles
    }
}
```

but this solutions is a lil bit ugly cause I should take care about this thing in an every style which might be override. Maybe there are exist some utilities/helpers which can help to handle it in a more nice way?

P.S. Don't ask me about this interesting requirements, it's just a *withStyle* feature of the MaterilUI and I wondered how to handle it right.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`_.invokeMap()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#invokeMap) and [`_.merge()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#merge) to generate a combine styled object from an array of style functions and a theme:

```js
const applyTheme = (styles, theme) =>
  _.merge(..._.invokeMap(styles, _.call, null, theme));

const style_1 = theme => ({
  header : {
      color : theme.primary,
      border: `1px solid ${theme.primary}`
    }
})

const style_2 = theme => ({
  header : {
      backgroundColor : theme.secondary,
      color : "red"
    }
})

const theme = { primary: 'red', secondary: 'blue' }

const result = applyTheme([style_1, style_2], theme)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```